# Styling ASP.Net forms with CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm transitioning a website from plain html to ASP.Net.

I have two forms in the website frmRegister and frmLogin

I have css for the each of these like this...

```
form#frmRegister .floatRight input{
width: 100%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 0.9em;
border: 1px solid #a1d19d;
font-weight: normal;
}

form#frmRegister .textRow input, form#frmRegister .textRow textarea, form#frmLogin                 .textRow input, form#frmLogin .textRow textarea, form#frmRegister .textRow select{
width: 90%;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 border: 1px solid #a1d19d;
}
```

but because asp renames the forms to aspNetform, the styles are not applied.

I tried adding aspNetform to the css but then every form gets given the same style.

I'm using master pages btw.

Answer (score 6):

Don't style your CSS by ID.  Use [CSS classes](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php) instead.

```
<form id="myForm" runat="Server" class="someClass">
```

in css:

```
.someClass {background-color: blue; color:red; }
```

Although technically, I've never applied css to a form, so I'm not 100% sure the above will work.  If I need to do that, I nest a div within the form, and apply the style to the div.  So I'd change

```
<form id="myForm" runat="Server" class="someClass">
...
</form>
```

to

```
<form id="myForm" runat="Server" >
   <div class="someClass">
      ...
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do I apply the cssclass to the asp:Panel or ContentPlaceHolder?

Comment: I usually apply it to the Panel, but if you're using Visual Studio, even a free version, Intellisense should help you to determine if the cssClass property is available for a given tag.

Comment: Problem is if I do this all my forms get given the same style, since there can be only one form tag.

Comment: Infact, cssClass doesn't even show up on <form > when I create one in the Master page.

Comment: Good point.  I updated the code to give a better answer.  "CssClass" is purely an asp.net thing.  You can just use "class" and it should work.

Comment: To clarify `CssClass` is usually a property found on ASP.NET server side controls, and `Class` is an attribute typically found on standard HTML elements.  The `CssClass` property on the server side control is often rendered by ASP.NET as a `Class` attribute on the resultant HTML element (in the HTTP response).

Comment: @David. That works if I have one form but I have two and I cant have more than one form tag in a masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the style based on the class name, instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with web forms, so there may be a better solution, but you could just address your forms via CSS classes rather than ids.

E.g., add a class `frmRegister` to that form tag, and then address it in CSS like this:

```
form.frmRegister .floatRight input{ width: 100%; 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ClientID` property of your controls?

Also on your css you can do something like:

```
form#<%=myControl.ClientID%>{
    /* css in here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forms represent a special element in a webforms app. Better to just define a class and apply that to your form, or even putting a div within the form and styling that.

Also, one big advantage over regular HTML is that you can stick all this in a master page. This way, you can tweak your overall page layout only in one place (the master page) and have those changes reflected on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding the styles in the pages/master page or is it in an external file? If you add the styles to the master page it will affect all of its child pages.